# Using UIActivityIndicator in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app I download kml files and show their data in the map.How to show an activity indicator while downloading the data(after tapping the UIButton that initializes the downloading process and stop it when downloading is finished and pins are populating the map)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply start loading of activity indicator in initial part like like in whole view only map is there then

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //I have use drag and drop method for activity indicator and map it with outlet without fail and then implement it.
    activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    activityIndicator.hidden = FALSE;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

The following method will **call after loading map** so,

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
      [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
      activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

I think it will work for you